# how to check for an empty .csv extension file in C#

Tags: c#, io

I have an input type file in my .aspx page.

```
<input type="file" id="BatchImportFile" runat="server">
```

When I am trying to check the `File.PostedFile.ContentLength` property for an empty file it is always showing value as 2 even if I upload an empty file.
I want to check an empty `.csv` file .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file that you uploaded simply was not empty. 2 bytes is the length of a Windows line terminator. Maybe it contains an empty line. Unicode BOM headers are also 2 bytes in length.

Use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check for this case.

Comment: or look for `string.Trim().Length`. It should be 0 for empty file.

Comment: can u be a bit elaborative how can I use file.PostedFile.ContentLength with String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace ??

Comment: Read the file into a string first so that you can use this method. You need to examine the content not just the length.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
if( new FileInfo( "file" ).Length == 0 )
{
//your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var file = controller.Request.Files[0];
if(file.ContentLength <= 2) 
{ // do something 

 }
```

Comment: I don't see how your answer is connected with question - what is controller?

Comment: Probably this answer assumes OP is using model-view-controler, but the question looks more like classic asp.net webforms.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27297773).

Comment: The answer point was this line if(file.ContentLength <= 2).  #Cleptus you are right. Thanks.